# Can't set TextView to VISIBLE

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, visibility

I set the following to visible in my onCreate method.

```
findViewById(R.id.noDesignsCallToAction).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In the XML, the view is set to visibility gone.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/go_ahead_create_something_n_it_s_really_easy_n_just_click_here_to_get_started"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/noDesignsCallToAction"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="LaunchCustomizer"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why won't the textview appear as visible in my app?

Comment: Can you post the entire layout XML?

Comment: Does it work if you inflate it and then you set its visibility ? Like *TextView tv = (TextView) findView...; tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);* and maybe your string res is empty ?

Comment: what actually want to do ?

Comment: Never saw any issue with setVisibility. Post your entire XML and the related java code. Probably, the view is outside of the window for some reason or you called setVisibility at wrong time... something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change textColor of your textview in layout file or check if any view is not overlapping your textview.

Comment: I had another textView overlapping the textView I was interested in. I can't exactly say how I fixed it because it required a lot of trial and error. Just one of those finicky layout xml issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the content view first. Otherwise you'll get an NPE as a result of the ID not being found in the active layout.

Use an instance (don't call `findViewById(id).setVisibility()` as it uses more memory compared to caching the TextView as a field) and then set the visibility.

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
TextView temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noDesignsCallToAction);
temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inflate it and then set its visibility.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.something);

TextView tv = (TextView)   findView...;     

tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and maybe string res is empty ?